# Div Not Floating Right Or Being inline with title

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want it so that when all the input fields are filled, the button automatically enables again but i am finding it hard to do so. I am using php to check the fields and html to enable/disable the button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $required = array('FName', 'LName', 'Email', 'Subject', 'Comments');

        $error = false;
        foreach($required as $field) {
            if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
                $error = true;
            }
            else{
                $error = false;
            }
        }

        if ($error) {
            } else {      
        }

    ?>
    <div class="ContentBox" style="width:auto;">
    <h1 class="Title">Contact Us</h1>
        <div class="contact_form">
            <form method="post" action="ThankYou.php">

                <div id="contact_left">
            <p>First Name: </p>
                    <input class="TextBox" type="text" name="FName">
            <p>Last Name: </p> 
                    <input class="TextBox" type="text" name="LName">
            <p id="HText">Email: (?)<span id="HSpan">Only For Verification Purposes</span></p> 
                <p><input class="TextBox" type="email" name="Email"></p>


            <p style="text-align:center;"><input class="Button_s" name="submit" type="submit value="Submit" id="submit" disabled="disabled"></p>

                    </div>
                <div id="contact_right">
            <p>Subject: </p> 
                    <input class="TextBox" type="text" name="Subject">
            <p>Comments: </p> 
                    <textarea id="content" rows="10" cols="40" name="Comments"></textarea>
                    </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        function check_input($data)
            {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
            }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP only runs on the server, not the browser -- you need JavaScript do do what you're trying to do.

Comment: for runtime checking you need jquery/javascript to enable/disable the button. use if(empty(field)) to check whether the fields are empty or filled.

Answer (score 1):

PHP code will be processed only in server side. PHP can process the input only after the user clicks the submit button.

You should use javascript in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use only HMTL and CSS to enable the "submit" button when all the fields are filled: http://jsfiddle.net/du97k26u/.

HTML:

```
<form method = "post">
    <input type = "text" placeholder = "First Name" required />
    <input type = "text" placeholder = "Last Name" required />
    <input type = "submit" value = "Process" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form > input {
    display: block;
}

form > input:invalid ~ input[type = "submit"] {
    display: none;
}
```